# How to upload video to Youtube with QNetworkAuth

Tags: c++, qt, google-oauth, qnetworkrequest

Using `QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow` to authorize with google's oauth2. The authorization is successful as well as using `GET` request (for example, obtaining list of videos from youtube channel).
But while `QNetworkAccessManager` provides user with a bunch of `post` method overloads:

```
QNetworkReply * post(const QNetworkRequest &request, QIODevice *data)
QNetworkReply * post(const QNetworkRequest &request, const QByteArray &data)
QNetworkReply * post(const QNetworkRequest &request, QHttpMultiPart *multiPart)
```

`QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow` has only:

```
QNetworkReply *post(const QUrl &url, const QVariantMap &parameters = QVariantMap());
```

It's easy to append a file using `QHttpMultiPart` & `QHttpPart::setBodyDevice()`. But I'm not sure how to use `QVariantMap` for video/file uploading.

Also, tried to use: `QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::networkAccessManager()` to get access to underlying network manager, but it gives 202 response code with `GET`. And, if using with authenticated url, `QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::createAuthenticatedUrl()`, the response code is 200, but reply content is empty (readAll() returns empty buffer). Doesn't work with `POST` as well.

Using QT 2nd day, so I may misunderstand some concepts. Thanks for any help & ideas.

Comment: Happy that someone asked this question.

Comment: Just curious whether you wouldnt mind making the full code available for this. I will in turn gift over some reputation as thanks. I am having a bit of trouble with this due to the lack of documentation.

Comment: @Akiva the code isn't that pretty, but it did upload a video for me https://github.com/x4t3a/YoutubeUploader/blob/master/youtube_wrapper.cpp#L98

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to work around it. But still, maybe there is the right solution to it.

```
QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow youtube{};
...
// authorization
...
auto multi_part = new QHttpMultiPart{ QHttpMultiPart::MixedType };
auto video_part = new QHttpPart{};
auto video = new QFile{ video_path };

if (!video->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) { return nullptr; }

video_part->setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QVariant("video/*"));
video_part->setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("Slug"));
video_part->setBodyDevice(video);
multi_part->append(*video_part);

QNetworkRequest req{youtube_videos_insert};
const QString bearer_format = QStringLiteral("Bearer %1");
const QString bearer = bearer_format.arg(youtube.token());
req.setRawHeader("Authorization", bearer.toUtf8());

youtube.networkAccessManager()->post(req, multi_part);
```